# Getting all records in one query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```js
const arr = await ThreadModel.distinct("_id", { user_uuid: "abc" });

const events = await EventModel.find({ thread_id: { $in: arr } }).limit(10);
```

The first query gets the `_id` field of all threads of a specific user which returns an array of `_id`s.
Then another query is performed to get events of the threads.

What if there are thousands or millions of records fetched in the first query? Would it be a long process?
What are the alternatives?

Note that i can't use the `$lookup` stage.

> **$lookup**
> Performs a left outer join to an **unsharded collection** in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing
> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Is that just an example?  If you only want 10 records, why not limit the list of IDs?  As a side note, passing thousands of IDs wouldn't be much of an issue.  Passing millions of GUIDs means you will have a 100MB query, which is possible, but it's going to take a little time.  Just the network traffic alone will take time.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yep, Just an example. Well, I have another choice:
If there are 1m users, I should create an event for a million times associated with `user_uuid`, so i don't need the first query, i can easily do `EventModel.find({ user_uuid: "abc" }).limit(10);` now creating 1m records is another headache.
This is a chat app, Events like "delete-message", "clear-history", "change-photo" are stored in the `events` collection, When users go online they get the events and apply them to their local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking users and threads in a Relational Database solves my problem.
It's also possible to write advanced queries.

**links:**

| user_uuid | thread_id |
| --- | --- |
| A-B-C-D-E | 1 |
| Y-D-G-R-W | 5 |

---

**events:**

| id | thread_id | data | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | {...} | 1630355818 |
| 102 | 5 | {...} | 1630355937 |

---

**SQL Query:**

```sql
SELECT `events`.* from `events` 
INNER JOIN `links` ON `events`.`thread_id` = `links`.`thread_id`
WHERE `links`.`user_uuid` = ? LIMIT 10
```